# Split words with a capital letter

Tags: prolog

I have this problem with extraction of text from a page. Sometimes i have this words:

```
EatAppleGood
```

but i want

```
Eat Apple Good
```

I obtained the three words together. How can i split the words with capital letter?

Comment: have a shoot: use this regex http://jason.diamond.name/weblog/2009/08/15/splitting-camelcase-with-regular-expressions/ and convert it to prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is rather different if you are using atoms vs strings (i.e. list of char codes), because these representations are about really different data types.

Anyway, make a copy of the input with

- the current word, initialized to empty
- an accumulator keeping words seen so far

Then decide how to handle blanks, etc...

To keep things simple, let's see the most idiomatic way: list of characters

```
% words_to_lowercase(String, Word, WordsSeen, Result)
%
words_to_lowercase([C|Cs], WordR, Words, Result) :-
    (   code_type(C, upper(L))
    ->  reverse(WordR, Word),
        WordsUpdated = [Word|Words],
        Updated = [L]
    ;   Updated = [C|WordR],
        WordsUpdated = Words
    ),
    words_to_lowercase(Cs, Updated, WordsUpdated, Result).

words_to_lowercase([], W, Seen, Result) :-
    reverse([W|Seen], Result).
```

that yields

```
?- words_to_lowercase("EatAppleGood",[],[],R), maplist(atom_codes,L,R).
R = [[], [101, 97, 116], [97, 112, 112, 108, 101], [100, 111, 111, 103]],
L = ['', eat, apple, doog].
```

You can get rid of the empty word at start (for instance) applying pattern matching in the base case:

```
words_to_lowercase([], W, Seen, Result) :-
    reverse([W|Seen], [[]|Result]).
```

*edit*: oops, I forgot to reverse the last word...

```
words_to_lowercase([], W, Seen, Result) :-
    reverse(W, R),
    reverse([R|Seen], [[]|Result]).
```

*edit* about the regex suggestion, you got in comment from Najzero, you could put to good use the [regex](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=regex) pack recently published. Start with

```
?- pack_install(regex).
```

then

```
?- [library(regex)].
?- regex('([A-Z][a-z]+)+', [], 'EatAppleGood', L),maplist(atom_codes,A,L).
L = [[69, 97, 116], [65, 112, 112, 108, 101], [71, 111, 111, 100]],
A = ['Eat', 'Apple', 'Good'].
```

since we have ready [downcase_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=downcase_atom/2), we can do

```
?- regex('([A-Z][a-z]+)+', [], 'EatAppleGood', L),maplist(atom_codes,A,L),maplist(downcase_atom,A,D).
L = [[69, 97, 116], [65, 112, 112, 108, 101], [71, 111, 111, 100]],
A = ['Eat', 'Apple', 'Good'],
D = [eat, apple, good].
```